# Can I have two tracking branches in Git (separate for push and rebase)?

Tags: git, git-workflow

The workflow in my team is as follows:

- At any time, we have more than one active branch; the development lands in 2 or more branches in parallel, for two different versions of an application (let's say, `v4` for the version to-be-released soon, and `v5`, to-be-released in distant future). We regularly merge `v4` into `v5`.
- No one ever works directly on `v4` or `v5`, we work on feature branches in our forks and create pull requests, pointing either to upstream `v4` or `v5` (using Atlassian Stash)

Let's say I create a new development. I create a new branch:

`git checkout -b SOMETHING_FOR_V4 v4`

Now I'm in `SOMETHING_FOR_V4`. I do commits and push:

`git push -u origin SOMETHING_FOR_V4`

I've set the remote tracking branch with `-u` so the next time I update something, I can do `git push` without specifying branch and Git will know where to push.

However time has passed and I want to rebase.

**I need to explicitly tell `git rebase origin/v4`**

Contrary, I could set `origin/v4` to my tracking branch at branch creation time, but then, when I push, I would have to always say `git push origin SOMETHING_FOR_V4` every time.

What I'd like to have is so that Git is intelligent enough to know on top of which to rebase.
If I just said `git rebase` after doing `git push -u`, it would take the remote tracking branch I specified when pushing, this is not what I want.

Basically I want to have **separate tracking branch used for `git push`** (the one I push to the first time) **and separate one for `git rebase`** (rebase on top of `v4` or `v5` depending from which I started [1]).

**Is it possible to get this kind of behavior?**

Alternatively, what command would I use to find out myself whether I am "closer" to `v4` or `v5` (I am thinking about automating fetch-and-rebase in an alias)?

[1] it could either rebase on top of what I started off from, say `v4`, or its remote, in this scenario `origin/v4`. Let's say I can handle keeping `v4` and `origin/v4` in sync myself.

Answer (score 2):

As it stands there is no built-in way to achieve what you are trying to do. But git wouldn't be git if you weren't able to handle this case yourself.

### Configuration

For this to function we have to configure the branch on which we want to rebase. Git gives you free hand in adding any configuration you can imagine; so let's call this configuration key `branch.<name>.rebase-upstream`.

To set `origin/v4` as the `rebase-upstream` for `SOMETHING_FOR_V4` we can simply do:

```
git configure branch.SOMETHING_FOR_V4.rebase-upstream origin/v4
```

### Shell script

Now we need a script which reads this configuration and passes it to `rebase`.

The following script will try to read the configuration for the current branch; it will warn you if you aren't on any branch right now or if no `rebase-upstream` configuration exists for the current branch.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

current_branch="$(git symbolic-ref --short -q HEAD)"
if [ $? == 1 ]; then
    echo "You are on no branch!" >&2
    exit 1
fi

upstream="$(git config --get branch.$current_branch.rebase-upstream)"
if [ $? == 1 ]; then
    echo "No rebase-upstream reference configured for $current_branch (config: branch.$current_branch.rebase-upstream)" >&2
    exit 1
fi

echo "Rebase $current_branch onto $upstream"
git rebase "$upstream"
```

### Usage

To easily use this script you now have two possibilities.

You either add the script somewhere in your path and call it `git-rebase-upstream` (or similar); the leading `git-` is the important part here. Git looks for executables in your path which start with `git-` and makes them available as command. Now you can use it via `git rebase-upstream`.

The more "portable" approach would add an alias which contains a shell function with the script. The advantage being that you only have to backup your global `.gitconfig` if you want to synchronize your git configuration and commands accross multiple machines.

Adding an alias called `rebase-upstream` would look like this:

```
git config --global alias.rebase-upstream '!f() { current_branch="$(git symbolic-ref --short -q HEAD)"; if [ $? == 1 ]; then echo "You are on no branch!" >&2; exit 1; fi; upstream="$(git config --get branch.$current_branch.rebase-upstream)"; if [ $? == 1 ]; then echo "No rebase-upstream reference configured for $current_branch (config: branch.$current_branch.rebase-upstream)" >&2; exit 1; fi; echo "Rebase $current_branch onto $upstream"; git rebase "$upstream"; }; f'
```

If you want to use a shorter alias (`ru`) for either approach you can use

```
git config --global alias.ru '!git rebase-upstream'
```

Comment: It looks promising, I will test it when I have more time, so far I gave you an upvote :)